# How can I create work history with perfection on my github account

Tags: git, github

everyone.
I have some problems to create "a good work history" for my new github account created in this year.
I created it in July and tried to "copy" someone's history.
At the first time I was very happy with the "perfect result" but it was only a sec,
Because I found some issues that I could see my history began in 2012 but others could see only history of this year.
I think it is because my account was created in this year.
Let me know if anyone has any solutions for this.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: is "perfection" an FOSS tool??

Comment: Is this about those little green squares on the weekly grid?

Comment: hi, Mingwei,
you are right.